# Quotient Map vs Embedding (Topology)

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

**Problem 1:**

Can any quotient $\tilde{X}$ of $X$ be embedded in $X$?
Moreover, does any (surjective) quotient map $\pi:X\to\tilde{X}$ left split with an (injective) embedding $\iota:\tilde{X}\to X$?

**Problem 2:**

Problem 1 vice versa!

**Hint:**

For the second claims we have:
A quotient map left splits with an embedding iff there is a continuous section.
An embedding right splits with a quotient map iff there is a continuous retraction

Comment: Consider $t \mapsto e^{it}$. If there is a (continuous, of course) section $\tilde{X} \to X$, that is an embedding of the quotient space into $X$.

Comment: Sorry what do u mean exactly: If ... then ? ...btw good mornin @DanielFischer =)

Comment: "Morning"? Ich wußte ja, daß in Bayern die Uhren anders ticken, aber so anders? In general, if $\pi \colon X \to \tilde{X}$ is a quotient map, there is no subspace of $X$ that is homeomorphic to $\tilde{X}$. The example $\pi \colon \mathbb{R}\to S^1;\; t\mapsto e^{it}$ gives an example. But if $\pi \colon X \to \tilde{X}$ is a quotient map (surjective is part of the definition I use), and there is a continuous section $\iota\colon\tilde{X}\to X$, then $\iota$ is an embedding, and we have a subspace of $X$ homeomorphic to $\tilde{X}$ (namely $\iota(\tilde{X})$).

Comment: Ja bissl durcheinander diffgeo halt ^^ ...How can we deduce the last statement?

Comment: I already gave an example of a quotient without a section at one of your previous questions. It is also an example where the quotient cannot be embedded in $X$.

Comment: What is the inverse of $\iota$? Writing it down makes it clear that it is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**

Counterexample: $\mathbb{R}$, $\{0,1\}$
Here, since any two points on the real line can be separately separated any injective map induces as initial topology the discrete one while since singletons are not open in the real line any surjective map induces as final topology the indiscrete one.
So, we see that in here neither a quotient can be an embedding nor an embedding can be a quotient.
Moreover, since the first claims don't hold here the second ones cannot hold either.

**Explanation:**

This counterexample shows very good what is actually happening:
While initial topologies become quite fine final topologies become quite coarse. They might meet in between, however, in general they don't.

**Outlook:**

A more sohisticated counterexample is given by: $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{S}$
It is a well known fact that the sphere is a quotient of the real line. On the other hand it can be shown that the sphere cannot be embedded into the real line.